# Adwords conversion tracking doesn't work

Tags: android, google-ads-api, conversion-tracking

I use following code to track a conversion:

```
AdWordsConversionReporter.reportWithConversionId(
                this.getApplicationContext(),
                "xxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "0.00", true);
```

It doesn't show any conversions in Adwords. It was working fine since my last update of the app. I rechecked conversionId and Label. They are correct. BTW, I added this code in onResume() of one of my activities.

And is there any other way to test it before production (Probably with adb)?

Edit:

I could see this message logged at info level:

```
09-29 15:37:34.061: I/GoogleConversionReporter(3757): Pinging: https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/1007040578/?bundleid=com.xxxxxxxx&appversion=3.1.0&osversion=4.2.1&sdkversion=ct-sdk-a-v2.1.0&gms=1&lat=0&timestamp=1411988.853&auto=1&usage_tracking_enabled=1&rdid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was no error, Just that it was taking time to update in dashboard.

Comment: I'm having that issue too but after a week its still not showing up.  Ping comes back with 200 response.  Even called them up and the conversion is setup properly in the client.  Code is the code generated on the site inserted into app.  I can see the Pinging go out too.

Answer (score 0):

I got a log as follows for implementing "Google Conversion tracking".`ACTAutomatedUsageReporterPrivate: sending ping: googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/957130180/…. ping successful`, but i can't able to see any changes in Google Adwords dashboard even after waiting 24 hours.

@JPM Conversion tracking for iOS App is not reflecting in Google Adwords dashboard because due to the following restriction of Google `"iOS conversion tracking is currently available only for ads that show in mobile apps on the Display Network"`

Google Adwords forces iOS App to use "Google Display Network".

```
https://www.en.adwords-community.com/t5/Tracking-Reporting/Mobile-App-Install-Campaigns-for-iOS-Tracking/m-p/440241#U440241
https://www.en.adwords-community.com/t5/Basics-for-New-Advertisers/Display-Network-Mobile-App-Install-Ads-where-are-they/td-p/419693
```

Google Display Network means providing “Ads for IOS App in specified websites”.
http://www.google.co.in/ads/displaynetwork/

Google Display Network – Starting Guide - http://www.google.co.in/ads/displaynetwork/get-started/#tab=create-campaign